# Python's difflib SequenceMatcher speed up

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, difflib

I'm using difflib SequenceMatcher (ratio() method) to define similarity between text files. While difflib is relatively fast to compare a small set of text files e.g. 10 files of 70 kb on average comparing to each other (46 comparisons) takes about 80 seconds.

The issue here is that i have a collection of 3000 txt files (75 kb on average), a raw estimation on how much time SequenceMatcher needs to complete the comparison job is 80 days!

I tried "real_quick_ratio()" and "quick_ratio()" methods, but they don't fit to our needs.

Is there any way to speed up the comparison process? 
If not, is there any other faster method to do such a task? Even if it is not in Python.

Answer (score 8):

The issue you're finding is very common, since `difflib` is not optimized. Here are some tricks I've found over the years while developing a tool that compares HTML documents.

### Files fit in memory

Create two lists, containing the lines from each file. Then call `difflib.SequenceMatcher` with the lists as parameters. The `SequenceMatcher` knows how to handle lists, and the process will be much faster since it is done on a line by line basis instead of char by char. This might reduce the precision.

Take a look at [fuzzy_string_cmp.py](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/blob/43aeb4482a3701a05a0c0c594d22321b9969c6b6/w3af/core/controllers/misc/fuzzy_string_cmp.py#L86-L99) and [diff.py](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/blob/43aeb4482a3701a05a0c0c594d22321b9969c6b6/w3af/core/controllers/misc/diff.py#L67-L120) to see how I'm doing exactly this.

### Alternative

There is a great library called [diff_match_patch](https://pypi.org/project/diff-match-patch/) which is available in pypi. The library will perform **fast** diffs between two strings and return the changes (line added, line equal, line removed).

By leveraging [diff_match_patch](https://pypi.org/project/diff-match-patch/) you should be able to create your own `dmp_quick_ratio` function.

In [diff.py](https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/blob/43aeb4482a3701a05a0c0c594d22321b9969c6b6/w3af/core/controllers/misc/diff.py#L30-L64) you can see how I'm using the library to get inspiration for creating `dmp_quick_ratio`.

My tests showed that using [diff_match_patch](https://pypi.org/project/diff-match-patch/) was 20 times faster than Python's `difflib`.

Answer (score 8):

There is a C implementation of `difflib.SequenceMatcher`, [cdifflib](https://pypi.org/project/cdifflib).

Replace the SequenceMatcher and all difflib operations will be about 4x faster

```
from cdifflib import CSequenceMatcher
import difflib
difflib.SequenceMatcher = CSequenceMatcher
```

Comment: Really faster! Thanks

Answer (score -6):

You can get a small speedup using pypy

http://pypy.org/

Comment: This recommendation is too generic.